# Copy rows of data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help me come up with a solution for the situation being explained below:

```
ID   name   address            age      hobby       GPA
---------------------------------------------------------
101  James  100 Garfield St     21      reading     3.13
101  James  100 Garfield St     21      writing     2.63
101  James  100 Garfield St     21      running     3.81
109  Tom    19 Lily Ave         19      dating      3.54
109  Tom    20 Lily Ave         19      climbing    2.76
109  Tom    21 Lily Ave         19      watching    3.91
```

I want to copy the set of rows with the same ID (eg. 101) and assign each set a State abbreviation(s) by running a single sql query. For instance: adding states CA, NJ, and DE to rows with an ID of 101, the result set is expected to look like this:

```
ID   name   address            age      hobby       GPA     state
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
101  James  100 Garfield St     21      reading     3.13     CA
101  James  100 Garfield St     21      writing     2.63     CA
101  James  100 Garfield St     21      running     3.81     CA
101  James  100 Garfield St     21      reading     3.13     NJ
101  James  100 Garfield St     21      writing     2.63     NJ
101  James  100 Garfield St     21      running     3.81     NJ
101  James  100 Garfield St     21      reading     3.13     DE
101  James  100 Garfield St     21      writing     2.63     DE
101  James  100 Garfield St     21      running     3.81     DE
```

Please keep in mind that everything else remains the same way as they were before the addition of the state abbreviations. Also assume I have more than three states to add and integrate to the query, say, I have all 50 states. Thank you for your time and effort in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? Given your table is not normalised, and the strange nature of your question, can we assume this is homework? Not that you cannot ask homework questions here but you should show some effort towards solving the problem. At least, explain the _reason_ behind the need for the output you describe.

Answer (score 0):

This should produce that result set:

```
select  x.*, y.st
from    tbl x
    join
        (select 'CA' as st union all
        select 'NJ' union all
        select 'DE') y
where   x.id = 101
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new table with IDs and States

```
ID  ST 
101 CA 
101 NJ
101 DE 
109 ..
```

then join that on your table

```
SELECT t.*, s.st
FROM tbl t
JOIN states s ON t.id = s.id
```